# SItuar un row hasta el principio de un dataTable siempre

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buen dia mi gente yo quisiera saber si tienen algun ejemplo de como poner un row siempre al principio de una tabla hecha con el plugin dataTable e buscado varias formas pero no lo logro me podrian ayudar por favor ?

Comment: Debes de agregar tu html de la tabla y tu codigo js actual para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Hola Memo, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Este sitio es un poco diferente a un foro u otros sitios. Aquí, el ejemplo lo debes proporcionar tu. Consulta esta guía: __[mcve]__. Usa este enlace para [edit] tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de agregar una nueva fila en datatable es:

```
dt_Empleados.row.add([
    "123",
    "Juan Pérez",
    "Administrativo"
]).draw();
```

Esto agregará la fila en la posición correspondiente al orden actual de la tabla.
Procura que tu enunciado de datatable sea algo como esto:

```
var dt_Empleados = $('#empleados').DataTable({
    "sDom": "... ...",
    "autoWidth": true,
    ...
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

Fíjate... con la "D" en mayúscula, no dataTable.

Respecto a poner la fila en primera posición, prueba con esto:

```
dt_Empleados.Rows.InsertAt(myDataRow, 0);
```

Comment: buen dia quier saber como tener ese row siempre en la misma posicion aun tenga activado el shorting